# How to paste a style sheet into a new document window in a Rally app

Tags: javascript, css, stylesheet, rally

I am trying to make a Rally app that shows User Story cards and then pops up a print window when a button is pressed. Everything works well except when pasting the html into the Custom HTML app in the Rally site. When I try this, the pop up window is not formatted correctly. The CSS does not apply to the print window which means that it will only print unformatted text.

The app has this code to make the print window:

```
    title = this.iterationCombobox.rawValue + ' Stories';

    options = "toolbar=1,menubar=1,scrollbars=yes,scrolling=yes,resizable=yes,width=1000,height=500";

    printWindow = window.open('', title, options);
    doc = printWindow.document;

    cardMarkup = this.down('#card');

    doc.write('<html><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="app.css"/><title>' + title + '</title>');
    doc.write('</head><body class="landscape">');
    doc.write(cardMarkup.getEl().dom.innerHTML);
    doc.write('</body></html>');
    doc.close(); 

    printWindow.print();
```

Most of this code is working, but this line is not working properly:

```
    doc.write('<html><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="app.css"/><title>' + title + '</title>');
```

The link part of the html links it to the css file (app.css), and this link works externally. However, building the app and then pasting it into the Custom HTML puts all the css inline and therefore takes away the app.css file. Because I want that file to format both the app and the print window, it's not working with the inline css. I tried to copy the style node for the app using various methods:

```
var ourStyle = document.styleSheets[2];
```

after finding that the 3rd stylesheet was the one I wanted. Then I tried adding this stylesheet to the print window's stylesheet using:

```
doc.styleSheets[2] = ourStyle;
```

I also tried:

```
doc.styleSheets.push(ourStyle);
```

but that did not work because styleSheets is an object and does not have a push method.

I am not sure how to copy the css styles so that they can be used for the print window, or how to find another way around this problem. Any help would be awesome! Thanks!

Also I know it would be possible to just type out all the tags within the html file, but I would really prefer an easier solution than that (because there is a lot of css code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get both the Rally CSS and the CSS that I put into the app, I had to do 2 separate things. Before opening up the new window, add a line:

```
var css = document.getElementsByTagName('style')[0].innerHTML;
```

Then, when writing html into the new document, put that css in between style tags:

```
doc.write('<html><head><style>' + css + </style></head>');
```

DISCLAIMER! This line will not work externally! It only works when you are within the Rally site.

To make sure that the Rally CSS is included in the app, I added these 2 functions to the code:

```
_injectContent: function(html, elementType, attributes, container, printWindow){
    elementType = elementType || 'div';
    container = container || printWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];

    var element = printWindow.document.createElement(elementType);

    Ext.Object.each(attributes, function(key, value){
        if (key === 'class') {
            element.className = value;
        } else {
            element.setAttribute(key, value);
        }
    });

    if(html){
        element.innerHTML = html;
    }

    return container.appendChild(element);
},

_injectCSS: function(printWindow){
    //find all the stylesheets on the current page and inject them into the new page
    Ext.each(Ext.query('link'), function(stylesheet){
            this._injectContent('', 'link', {
            rel: 'stylesheet',
            href: stylesheet.href,
            type: 'text/css'
        }, printWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0], printWindow);
    }, this);
}
```

Finally, add this line to the function where you are building your new window:

```
this._injectCSS(printWindow);
```

This will inject the Rally CSS into the new window.

Answer (score 0):

you can check it

```
      'http://jsfiddle.net/ni3net/zPhP3/'
```

it's working fine..

may be your title variable having some string terminator character like (',", >, <)